# java Collection facade

Tags: java, collections, facade

I need to create a facade that takes TreeSet or HashSet.
it's constructor has to look like this:

```
CollectionFacadeSet(java.util.Collection<java.lang.String> collection)
```

I import java collections and use this line:

```
Collections <String> collection = new Collections<>();
```

BUT, java would not accept it, I get an error:

> - The type Collections is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments
>
>   - The type Collections is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>

any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Collection` (singular)? Also, why would you instantiate a `Collection` anyway?

Answer (score 7):

`java.util.Collections` (notice the plural form) is a helper class with many static methods to manipulate `Collection`s.
`java.util.Collection` (singular) is the base class for all of the JDK's built-in collections (`List`s, `Set`s, etc.).

TL;DR - you're importing the wrong class.

P.s.:
Note that `java.util.Collection` is an `abstract` class, you won't be able to instantiate it.

Comment: Regarding your note, we might add that the OP does not need to initialize his `collection` variable with a `new` anyway. I believe this variable gets its value from the constructor, where the OP gets a concrete instance of `Collection`.

Answer (score 2):

Although your variable can be a Collection, the object it holds a reference to must be a concrete type; you can't instantiate Collection (or a Collections as you attempted).

Try something like this:

```
Collection<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
```

But if you need a Set, use one:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you are using java.util.Collections class which is not a generic class, So you can't parameterize it to String type.you should use java.util.Collection instead.

Secondly, Since Collection is an Interface so have to make the object of its implementation classes.

you can use  -

```
Collection <String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you are facing is because you are trying to instantiate a variable of type 'Collections'. Instead, it is possible to change the method to accept any Object that uses the 'Set' interface:

```
public Set<String> CollectionFacadeSet(Set<String> mySet)
```

If you wish to have a specific type of set returned, such as a HashSet or TreeSet, simply change the return parameter accordingly. Therein, you can now set your collection to your chosen set type:

```
Collection<String> myCollection = CollectionFacadeSet(someSet);
```

Comment: Thank you @Unheilig for reformatting my code. I posted this on my phone and was not fully aware how to change it into the proper format :)